# Blender cycles render is showing one object as almost transparent

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

When i render my image in eevee i get what i want, but for some stuff i need to work, i have to be in cycles. But when i render in cycles, one of the objects displays almost transparent- i see it's shadow through it on the wall, but i also see a slight outline.

In eevee:

[image]

In cycles:

[image]

Here is my node tree:

[image]

In eevee im not showing much, because it comes out good and im trying to make this as a surprise for a friend.

Comment: What does your shader node tree look like? Please [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/182711/edit) and add more information that will help other users understand your question.

Comment: Best is if you could upload the .blend file. There's probably some setting or whatever that we need to look for but that we can't see in your provided information.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it! I had my alpha down to really low on the shader